# Click event in ul and li dropdown menu from input field, It is a suggestion bar

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to have a click functionality on the list item which will trigger a function in component and will fill the input field also.

By far I have tried using `(click)` ,`(ngModelChange)` and `(change)` but none of this is seems to working. It seems Im not able to click on the droped down list.

TEMPLATE

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" [formControl]="queryField" placeholder="Search" (blur)="myFunction()" (focus)="myFunction1()" />
<ul class="filter-select form-rounded" >
<li class="filter-select-list" *ngFor="let result of results" 
(click)="selectedProduct($event)">
{{result.productName}}
</li>
</ul>
```

COMPONENT

```
selectedProduct(){
    console.log('Hello');
}
```

CSS

```
.filter-select {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding : 0;
  z-index: 99;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter-select-list{
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

.filter-select-list:hover{
  background-color:gainsboro;
}
```

I want the function to fired.

Comment: you are sending event as an argument but not using it as a parameter

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], as it currently stands, this is not.

Answer (score 1):

Set `[(ngModel)]` and on click of li, pass `result.name` like this: `(click)="selectedProduct(result.productName)"` as `$event` works only with `form-input` not `<li>` or `<div>`

Template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" [(ngModel)]="queryField" placeholder="Search" (blur)="myFunction()" (focus)="myFunction1()" />


<ul class="filter-select form-rounded" >

    <li class="filter-select-list" *ngFor="let result of results" 
    (click)="selectedProduct(result.productName)">
        {{result.productName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

TS:

```
selectedProduct(event) {
    this.queryField = event
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxn58w)**

Comment: Hi its not working. Please check the question as I have done some editing.

Comment: It is working in the demo, please fork the demo. make the changes there and share

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, make below changes

1. On Click pass **result** instead of **$event** - `(click)="selectedProduct(result)"`
2. Update the value of the `queryField` using the `setValue()` method.

`selectedProduct(val){
    this.queryField.setValue(val.productName);
}`

working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz2nr2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  queryField = new FormControl('');
  results = [
    {productName:"p1"},
    {productName:"p2"},
    {productName:"p3"}
  ]
  selectedProduct(val){
    this.queryField.setValue(val.productName);
}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" [formControl]="queryField" placeholder="Search" (blur)="myFunction()" (focus)="myFunction1()" />
<ul class="filter-select form-rounded" >
<li class="filter-select-list" *ngFor="let result of results" 
(click)="selectedProduct(result)">
{{result.productName}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `$event` if you don't want to use it as a parameter in `ts file`.

**Your Updated Code**

> Template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" [formControl]="queryField" placeholder="Search" (blur)="myFunction()" (focus)="myFunction1()" />
<ul class="filter-select form-rounded" >
<li class="filter-select-list" *ngFor="let result of results" 
(click)="selectedProduct()">
{{result.productName}}
</li>
</ul>
```

> Component

```
selectedProduct(){
    console.log('Hello');
}
```